# How to exclude starting point from linspace function under numpy in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, linspace

I want to exclude starting point from a array in python using numpy. How I can execute?  For example I want to exclude 0, but want to continue from the very next real number(i.e want to run from greater than 0) following code `x=np.linspace(0,2,10)`

Comment: Please, share your codes and errors here. Also, explain more what you want.

Comment: To exclude 0 use `np.linspace(0,2,11)[1:]`. To exclude both 0 and 2 use `np.linspace(0,2,12)[1:-1]`.

Comment: A supplement： `np.linspace(2, 0, 10, endpoint=False)`

Answer (score 6):

```
x=np.linspace(0,2,10)[1:] #remove the first element by indexing
print(x)
[0.22222222 0.44444444 0.66666667 0.88888889 1.11111111 1.33333333
 1.55555556 1.77777778 2.        ]
```

Answer (score 6):

Kind of an old question but I thought I'll share my solution to the problem.

Assuming you want to get an array

```
[0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.]
```

you can make use of the endpoint option in np.linspace() and reverse the direction:

```
x = np.linspace(2, 0, 10, endpoint=False)[::-1]
```

the `[::-1]` reverses the array so that it ends up being in the desired sequence.